# Ensuring byte integrity when removing embedded file from PDF

Tags: java, pdf, hash, pdfbox, attachment

Quite a cryptic topic title. Let me try and explain what the issue is as best as I can.

I'm working on a project in which we have to ensure integrity of PDF files. We use SHA 256 hashes that we compute from the raw bytes of a PDF file. The computed hash is put into a txt file and embedded in the PDF it belongs to using Apache PDF Box, so that we can validate the document later.

When we validate a PDF, we use PDF Box to extract the txt file from the PDF.

Before computing the hash of a PDF, we first ensure that there are no embedded files:

```
public static byte[] removeEmbeddedFiles(PDDocument doc) throws IOException {
    PDDocumentNameDictionary names = new PDDocumentNameDictionary(doc.getDocumentCatalog());
    names.setEmbeddedFiles(new PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode());
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().setNames(names);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    doc.save(baos);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

This is working fine. However, this approach doesn't work when the original file already contains an embedded file. For these PDF documents, we'd like to compute the hash, add it to the embedded files list. Then later upon validation, we'd like to remove only the hash file, compute the hash and compare it to the original hash.

That approach doesn't work. It seems that everytime that we inspect or modify the PDDocumentNameDictionary there is some change made to the PDF in a way that it visually is still the same document, but the raw bytes actually differ.

So, the question is really: is there a way in which we can take a PDF file with PDF Box, embed a file, later remove that embedded file and obtain a document that is equal to the original document on a byte level?

I really hope that I explained the issue clear and comprehensively.

I thought of a workaround by extracting all embedded files, clear the name dictionary of de PDF as above and concatenate the PDF and extracted files into one byte[] and then compute the hash. While this would work, I'm still wondering if the original approach of just removing the hash file is feasible.

Comment: It can't be the same byte sequence if it originally contained a file and then none. What you're asking for is a kind of "Schrödinger's cat" type of format.

Comment: Consider adding the changes in an incremental update. You can then simply get the original file by truncating after the previous revision.

Comment: @Tilman, may be I wasn't exactly clear about what I'm trying to do. Let me rephrase. Suppose I have a PDF A with an attachment 1. I compute the hash of A1. Then I add a second attachment and get A1+2. Then, I take 2 out and end up with A1, visually the same PDF as I started with. I then again compute the hash, but it is different then the hash I previously got from the first A1.

Comment: Then what mkl mentioned is the thing for you.

Comment: This sounds like you're re-inventing digital signatures, a well established functionality in PDF. Probably makes more sense to use that rather than re-inventing a (non-compatible) wheel.

Comment: I know. Unfortunately, the choice had already been made long before I joined the project. That ship has sailed...

Comment: verhade, just out of interest, have you somehow got that project finished? How? Or was it stopped? As @David mentioned, this essentially is digital signing attempted in an extremely non-interoperable way, and I'm kind of interested in what alternative approaches I might stumble over one day... ;)

Comment: Well, we took another approach that worked for us. Quite some time has passed and I since have left the company so I can't explain what it exactly was we did. I can tell you that we chose a different approach than the usual PKI signing because we needed a solution for the long term (signatures that can still be validated over 30 years from now for example). That's why we used the KSI approach using hashes and Merkle trees.